# Using a z-test for proportion in place of Chi-Square

Tags: chi-squared-test, z-test

Here's the study:
Pam knows from prior research that children who are seated in a room with 4 doors are equally likely to pick any door when asked which door they would choose then leaving the room. Pam wants to demonstrate that children labeled by a psychologist as oppositional are more likely to choose the
door behind them.
◦She recruits 80 children with the diagnosis and tests her
hypothesis.

The answer key says to use Chi-Square goodness of fit. My problem is that this will not answer the research question: whether or not oppositional children are more likely to choose the door behind them. It will only tell us if the model of all doors equally likely is a good fit. I was curious if I could just set up a z-test for proportions with two categories: "doors not behind" and "door behind." Would this work?

Comment: A two-tailed normal approximation to a z-statistic like $\frac{\hat{p}-p_0}{\sqrt{p_0\,(1-p_0)/n}}$ and a chi-squared approximation to the chi-squared statistic are equivalent.  Consequently, any time you decide you could regard a chi-squared as suitable, a normal approximation will be exactly as suitable. When you have a one-sided (/directional) alternative instead of a two-sided alternative, naturally the chi-squared is not suitable for that situation even if the distribution approximation is okay but the z-test using the normal approximation would still be suitable.

Comment: You begin with "4 doors are equally likely" and then say "oppositional [children] are more likely to choose the door behind them." (More likely than what?) // My answer focuses on probability of back door. It does not envision different probabilities for front and two side doors. So if front has probability .1, sides .3 each, and back as .3 > .25 I still call that "oppositional." // Please clarify exactly what _**you**_ mean by "oppositional". Please see Comment by @whuber below.

Comment: @DougLynch, I think you are correct that the question isn't clear enough to make a chi-square goodness-of-fit test the obvious choice. ... Practically, using a gof test and then looking at the counts to see which door had a higher prevalence --- or looking at the standardized residuals --- would make sense.  ... In the real world, I might go with BruceET's approach, which I think is what you suggest in the question. ...  Or I might calculate multinomial proportions and confidence intervals for each as a sort of simultaneous comparison.  I bet not everyone will like that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Eighty is a large enough sample size that you could
use the normal approximation to a binomial distribution. It seems that there are various way to interpret the behavior of "oppositional' children. I will assume that you wish to test $H_0: p \le .25$ against $H_a: p > .25.$ (A traditional chi-squared test would test that all doors are equally likely against the alternative that they are not equally likely.)

If you get 27 children leaving by the rear door, then here is output for a z-test from Minitab statistical software.

```
Test and CI for One Proportion 

Test of p = 0.25 vs p > 0.25

Sample   X   N  Sample p  95% Lower Bound  Z-Value  P-Value
1       27  80  0.337500         0.250541     1.81    0.035
```

Because the P-value is less than or equal to $0.05 = 5\%,$ you can reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.

The null distribution (distribution assuming $H_0$ is true) is $\mathsf{Binom}(n=80, p=1/4).$ If $X$ has this distribution, you can standardize to
approximate $P(X \ge 27),$ which is the P-value of this test. After standardizing you can use
printed tables of the standard normal distribution to find the P-value. So it is not necessary to use
software to solve your problem.

Another approach would be to use an exact binomial test. Minitab will also do an exact binomial test, but for variety, I will show results of `binom.test` from R:

```
 binom.test(27, 80, p=.25, alt="greater")

        Exact binomial test

data:  27 and 80
number of successes = 27, number of trials = 80, 
 p-value = 0.04989
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.25
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2500512 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                0.3375
```

In this case a statistical calculator or statistical software would be convenient to
find $P(X \ge 27) = 1 - P(X \le 26) = 0.0499.$
In R, the computation looks like this:

```
1 - pbinom(26, 80, .25)
[1] 0.04988718
```

The figure below shows the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(80, 0.25)$. The exact binomal P-value is the sum of the heights of the bars to the right of the dotted vertical line. The approximate normal P-value is the area under the approximating normal
density curve to the right of that line.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
x = 0:80;  PDF = dbinom(x, 80, .25)
plot(x, PDF, lwd=2, type="h", main="PDF of BINOM(80,.25)")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=26.5, col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
mu = 80*.25;  sg = sqrt(80*.25*.75)
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), add=T, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

Comment: You have interpreted "more likely" as meaning "the chance of choosing the door behind them exceeds $1/4.$"  However, the correct interpretation is "the chance of choosing the door behind them is greater than the chances associated with any of the other three doors."  That's a different event.

Comment: @whuber. After looking at this for a while, I am still not sure exactly what null and alternative hypotheses OP may have in mind. So I have settled for trying to be clear about what I'm doing.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks. Fixed it.